# An entire function with finite covering group is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, covering-spaces

Let $f$ be an entire function. Think of it as a covering space of $\mathbb{C}$ (perhaps with isolated punctures) to $\mathbb{C}$ (perhaps with isolated punctures). Suppose we know there is only a finite number of covering transformations, $\{\varphi\}_{i=1}^n$:
$$ f(\varphi_i(z)) = f(z).$$
How to show $f$ is a polynomial ?

**Partial answer:** The function $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$ is entire in both variables. It is only zero when $z=\varphi_i(w)$ for some $i$, so we may write 
$$\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} = e^{g(z,w)} \prod_{i=1}^n (z-\varphi_i(w)).$$
Now setting $w=0$, and denoting $w_i = \varphi_i(0)$, we obtain:
$$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z} = e^{g(z,0)} \prod_{i=1}^n (z-w_i)=$$
$$ e^{g(z,0)} (z^n - (\sum w_i) z^{n-1} + \ldots + (-1)^n \prod w_i). $$
To show this is a polynomial amounts to showing $g(z,0)$ is a constant.

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but this is what I would try: if $f$ is not a polynomial, then it has an essential singularity at $\infty$, and therefore the fibers are $f^{-1}(\{w\})$ are infinite. If we knew that the group of covering transformation is transitive on fibers, we would be done. Sadly, I never learned if an entire function must be a regular cover...

Comment: Entire functions are in general not regular covers.

Comment: Are you assuming anything special about your entire function? Just curious, because there are examples (constructed by Gross, of infinite order) where the set of asymptotic values is the whole plane, i.e., where $f$ is not a covering over any point in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to prove is false. I will be using an example given by Alex Eremenko [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147110/surjective-entire-functions-without-critical-points). Take
$$
f(z)= \int_{0}^z \exp(t^2)dt. 
$$
Eremenko observed that $f$ is an entire function without critical points whose image is the ${\mathbb C}$. Let us identify its covering transformations $\phi$, i.e. homeomorphisms ${\mathbb C}\to {\mathbb C}$ such that $f\circ \phi=f$. It is easy to see that $\phi$ has to be biholomorphic, hence, of the form 
$$
\phi(z)=az+b, a\ne 0. 
$$ 
Take the equation $f(az+b)=f(z)$ and differentiate it twice with respect to $z$. We obtain first $\exp((az+b)^2)= \exp(z^2)$ and then 
$$
a(az+b)= z. 
$$
Thus, $a=\pm 1$, $b=0$. Therefore, there are exactly two deck-transformations,  $z\mapsto \pm z$. However, $f(z)$ is clearly not a polynomial.